# Play sound using timer on Android (Chrome) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, html5-audio

I have tried so many different methods to make a javascript timer ring a tablet once over. I used the following functions/calls:

```
$('#play-button').click(function(){ audio.play(); });}
```

and this code in html

```
<audio id="audiotag1" preload="auto" controls="false" autoplay="autoplay">
   <source src="buzz.mp3" />
</audio>
```

It works great on windows 7 OS, but not on phones. 
Any other method is welcome, or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your question has been asked before

#### Which approach?

You can play audio with `<audio>` tag or `<object>` or `<embed>`. 
Lazy loading(load when you need it) the sound is the best approach if its size is small. You can create the audio element dynamically, when its loaded you can start it with `.play()` and pause it with `.pause()`.

#### Things we used

We will use `canplay` event to detect our file is ready to be played.

There is no `.stop()` function for audio elements. We can only pause them. And when we want to start from the beginning of the audio file we change its `.currentTime`. We will use this line in our example `audioElement.currentTime = 0;`. To achieve `.stop()` function we first pause the file then reset its time.

We may want to know the length of the audio file and the current playing time. We already learnt `.currentTime`above, to learn its length we use `.duration`.

#### Example Guide

1. When document is ready we created an audio element dynamically
2. We set its source with the audio we want to play.
3. We used 'ended' event to start file again.

> When the currentTime is equal to its duration audio file will stop
>   playing. Whenever you use `play()`, it will start from the beginning.

4. We used `timeupdate` event to update current time whenever audio `.currentTime` changes.
5. We used `canplay` event to update information when file is ready to be played.
6. We created buttons to play, pause, restart.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.soundjay.com/misc/sounds/bell-ringing-01.mp3');
    
    audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.play();
    }, false);
    
    audioElement.addEventListener("canplay",function(){
        $("#length").text("Duration:" + audioElement.duration + " seconds");
        $("#source").text("Source:" + audioElement.src);
        $("#status").text("Status: Ready to play").css("color","green");
    });
    
    audioElement.addEventListener("timeupdate",function(){
        $("#currentTime").text("Current second:" + audioElement.currentTime);
    });
    
    $('#play').click(function() {
        audioElement.play();
        $("#status").text("Status: Playing");
    });
    
    $('#pause').click(function() {
        audioElement.pause();
        $("#status").text("Status: Paused");
    });
    
    $('#restart').click(function() {
        audioElement.currentTime = 0;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h2>Sound Information</h2>
    <div id="length">Duration:</div>
    <div id="source">Source:</div>
    <div id="status" style="color:red;">Status: Loading</div>
    <hr>
    <h2>Control Buttons</h2>
    <button id="play">Play</button>
    <button id="pause">Pause</button>
    <button id="restart">Restart</button>
    <hr>
    <h2>Playing Information</h2>
    <div id="currentTime">0</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it works on windows 7, but it does not work in a timer on android.

Comment: For some reason, and in order for it to work on android, it has to be triggered by a button the first time, before it could be automatically called by the timer function...

Comment: This is very weird, it work on Chrome, it work on iOS, it work on Firefox and Safari but not on Android. I think that the problem comes from your code, try to change your question and add more exemple or snippets. @Maleka